# Overriding classes and functions in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm writing a child theme and need to modify part of the parents theme's core functions.

To do this I would normally create a new class / function with the same name but the theme that I am using doesnt make use of the

```
if (function_exists('function_name'))
```

or

```
if (class_exists('class_name'))
```

What other options do I have to override this parent theme without me needed to modify the parent theme.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find a complete guide for overriding or functions that are created in parent theme functions file with prioriry and other things.... [A Guide to Overclass files riding Parent Theme Functions in Your Child Theme](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623)

Answer (score 0):

i think if you add same name of class or function then it take from child theme function and class then it take from parent.

For ex.

**Child Theme**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'function_name' ) ) {
  function function_name(){
    echo 'This is child theme';
  }
}
```

**Parent Theme**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'function_name' ) ) {
  function function_name(){
    echo 'This is parent theme';
  }
}
```

**Same for class**

Comment: I would have to change the parent theme to make this work. This would not be ideal as the parent theme updates quite a lot.

Comment: ok but if you try above then it work in child theme. if you get result then mark it answer so other get from here